# Can't transfer string from C to Ada

Tags: c, ada

I am trying to transfer a string from a **C** routine to an Ada application.  Instead of reading from a NI device I hard coded a string in the **C** file routine.  The string does transfer across but there are other non-characters with it. The string is HELLO.

```
BUFFER = UH~I?H~C?^P?E?HELL?E?O?
```

The C routine is:

```c
#include "gpib_intf.h"

#define MAX_SIZE 350

static ViStatus status, StatusSession;
static ViSession inst, defaultRM;
static char stringinput[256];
static ViUInt32 rcount, retCount;
static ViUInt32 BytesToWrite;
static unsigned char buffer[MAX_SIZE];

void setupDefaultRM()
{
   status = viOpenDefaultRM (&defaultRM);
   if (status < VI_SUCCESS)
      {
         printf("Could not open a session to the VISA Resource Manager!\n");
         exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

   status = viOpen (defaultRM, "GPIB0::1::INSTR", VI_NULL, VI_NULL, &inst);
   if (status < VI_SUCCESS)
      {
         printf("Could not open a session to the GPIB Device!\n");
         exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
}

void writeVI(char* stringinput)
{
   BytesToWrite = (ViUInt32)strlen(stringinput);
   status = viWrite (inst, (ViBuf)stringinput, BytesToWrite, &rcount);
}

void readVI()
{
   /*memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));*/
   const unsigned char version[5] = "HELLO";
   printf("\n");
   printf("version = %s\n", version);

   /*
   status = viRead (inst, buffer, MAX_SIZE, &retCount);
   if (status < VI_SUCCESS)
   {
      printf ("Error reading a response from the device.\n");
      }
   */
   /*return version;*/
}
```

The Ada code reading it is:

```ada
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------
   -- READVI
   --
   -- read from GPIB device
   --
   function READGPIB return STRING is
      
      function READVI return STRING is
      version : char_array(size_t);
      pragma Import (C, version, "readVI");
         
      begin
         --return "     0";
         return To_Ada(version, Trim_Nul => True);
      end;

   begin
      --Text_IO.Put_Line(READVI);
      return READVI;
   end READGPIB;
```

Comment: The function readVI defined in the C source code does not return a string, but the function READVI declared in the Ada code does return a string. the return statement in the C code is commented out. Furthermore, it does not appear that your Ada code uses the packages Interfaces.C and Interfaces.C.Strings.

Comment: Your Ada imports the C _function_ `readVI` as a `char_array`. No wonder you get garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem based upon Simon's recommendation.

C code

```
/*
 *  Read from a GPIB device
*/
unsigned char* readVI()
{
   status = viRead (inst, buffer, MAX_SIZE, &retCount);
   /* If successful read */
   if (status == VI_SUCCESS)
   {
      /* copy data into return buffer */
      strcpy(buff, buffer);
   }
   return buff;
}
```

Ada Code

```
       -------------------------------------------------------------------------
   -- READVI
   --
   -- read from GPIB device
   --
   procedure READGPIB is
      
      function READVI return Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr
        with
          Import,
          Convention => C,
          External_Name =>"readVI";
      
   begin
     declare
        Str : STRING := Interfaces.C.Strings.Value (READVI);
     begin
        for I in MSG3235_TYPE'Range loop
           GLOBALS.BUFFER(I) := Str(I);
           exit when Str (I) = ASCII.CR or Str (I) = ASCII.LF or Str (I) = ASCII.SEMICOLON;
         end loop;
     end;
  end READGPIB;
```

Answer (score 4):

You’ve posted a version of the C code that looks as if it was from an early development stage. If that’s what you’re actually using it’s a wonder that you saw anything with `HELLO` in it at all, if for no other reason than that on the C side `readVI` is a *void* *function*, which corresponds to an Ada procedure, whereas the Ada side thinks it’s a `char_array (size_t)`, whatever that means (`size_t` is a type, not a number).

On the C size, you want

```c
char *readVI();
```

and on the Ada side the corresponding declaration is

```ada
function Read_VI return Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr
with
  Import,
  Convention => C,
  External_Name => "readVI";
```

Putting it together, the C side might be

```c
#include <string.h>
static char buffer[128];

char *readVI()
{
  strcpy(buffer, "Hello!");
  return buffer;
}
```

and the Ada side

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Interfaces.C.Strings;

procedure Joseph is
   function Read_VI return Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr
   with
     Import,
     Convention => C,
     External_Name => "readVI";
begin
   Put_Line ("received '"
               & Interfaces.C.Strings.Value (Read_VI)
               & "'");
end Joseph;
```

Comment: Assuming that `char_array` and `size_t` are from `Interfaces.C`, then `char_array (size_t)` is a constrained subtype of `char_array` indexed by the entire range of `size_t`.

Comment: @JeffreyR.Carter, yes, now you mention it; I was more wondering what OP thought it meant.

Comment: Thanks Simon.  I am now getting a correct response back to the Ada code.  I also changed the code to read from the GPIB device and that is working also.  Next question is I need to return this to other Ada code so I changed the procedure to a function to return the string but I am getting a length check failed when I process RESPONSE := Joseph.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39754289/40851) will help? (read down to "declare block")